# Worklight: Protected resources unexpectedly becomes Unprotected automatically

Tags: java, security, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I have protected some of my resources as per Worklight guide to protect static url, console etc.

[http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Fr_protecting_ibm_worklight_console.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_protecting_ibm_worklight_console.html)

and the realm i have defined for it is done as per Custom_Authenticator_and_Login_Module.pdf guide.

I have below config settings:

```
<staticResources>
        <resource id="worklightConsole" securityTest="PushApplication-custom-securityTest">
             <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns> 
            <urlPatterns>/apps/services/preview*</urlPatterns>           
        </resource>
</staticResources>
```

When i applied that time both URLs were protected, now after two days when i am checking it again, only one is protected (preview is protected) this time.

Please suggest, is this known issue in WL v5.0.5 ? because currently i am running on this one.

I have one workaround on this security flaw, to implement Java EE security filters - as watchman for all requests.

My **authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<securityTests>
      <mobileSecurityTest name="myMobileSecurity">
            <testUser realm="myAppRealm"/>
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
        </mobileSecurityTest>
        <customSecurityTest name="PushApplication-custom-securityTest">                             
                <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="PushAppRealm"/>   
            </customSecurityTest> 
        <customSecurityTest name="myAppSecurityTestCustom">                             
                <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="myAppRealm"/>   
            </customSecurityTest> 
    </securityTests>

    <realms>

        <realm loginModule="Strongmy" name="myAppRealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-page" value="login.html"/>
        </realm>
        <realm loginModule="PushAppLoginModule" name="PushAppRealm">                                                
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.BasicAuthenticator</className>   
                <parameter name="basic-realm-name" value="PushAppRealm"/>                                                  
        </realm>
        <realm loginModule="requireLogin" name="WorklightConsole">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
        </realm>
    </realms>

    <loginModules>
         <loginModule name="PushAppLoginModule">
            <className>com.my.services.myAuthModule</className>
        </loginModule>
        <loginModule name="Strongmy">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="requireLogin">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

    </loginModules>
```

Any other suggestions are highly welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security tests you can put in a customSecurityTest are meant for protecting mobile environments, not for [protecting Worklight Console](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/r_protecting_ibm_worklight_console.html). From the name of your securityTest, it sounds like one you are indeed applying it to a mobile environment...

1. How does your authenticationConfig.xml look like?
2. What is wrong with using the pre-defined Worklight Console security test? ([you can also extend it to use LDAP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#security)).

Comment: Please see my config above. I have not tried pre-defined WL console Security test, kindly guide me how i can extend it in order to use LDAP? Currently in am using one custom (com.my.services.myAuthModule) module for validating against LDAP, should i just replace the class name for pre-defined test of console? Thanks

Comment: There is a training module for that... please see my edited answer.